# calling internal method for each object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback

I have a "class" with properties and methods. And I have instances of that class in an array in some other place in the code. Now I want to iterate through all of them and for each call a method. Something like this:

```
arr.forEach(draw());
```

But of course it looks up a global function draw() which is not there. How do I access object's methods in this situation?

I am new to javascript, so I assume it might be a stupid question, but I can't find an answer for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) takes a callback that accepts 3 arguments, the array element, the index, and the array.  You only need the first.  Wrap your call to `draw()` in an anonymous function and invoke it on the element from the function call.

```
arr.forEach(function(elem) { elem.draw(); });
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading it 10 times I finally got the logic behind. It is not that obvious after all.

Answer (score 1):

here is the documentation of the forEach function https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx

**forEach** first parameter is an *callback* function... that function receives 3 parameters, the first one is each object in that array.

```
arr.forEach(function(element){
  draw()
});
```

Where **element** is the object you want to access.

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now! Except I still don't get how to get the element. Maybe I should just use good old for loop....